Access Denied Error when Trying to Read Company Page Data
I have a LinkedIn developer app and I want to read the data on my company's LinkedIn page. I have generated the access token and have the following permission: r_dma_admin_pages_content.
In Postman, after setting the auth token and adding LinkedIn-Version: 202306 in the header, I send the following GET request:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/<org_id>

However, I receive the following response:
{
    "status": 403,
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: organizations.GET.NO_VERSION"
}

I have the following concerns and questions:

Is the permission r_dma_admin_pages_content sufficient for reading the page data?
Is the endpoint URL correct for reading the post data?

What is the best and correct approach for this task?
Details:

I have included the LinkedIn-Version: 202306 in the headers.
I have verified that my access token is valid.

Any help or guidance on how to properly access and read the company page data using the LinkedIn API would be greatly appreciated.
